# How does Hoisting in JavaScript work when dynamic allocating memory (declare varible in run-time)?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

As I read from a book, there a phase just before the execution phase called Creation Phase which set up spaces for declared varibles with undefined as default value. When a varible is assigned to a value, that value will be stored in that space.

So what if I declare an array whose length is known in runtime, how are these spaces set up in Creation Phase and on which part of the memory are these elements of the array stored?

Comment: Same process. ie `var arr = []`: `arr` is initialized to undefined in the preprocessing step. Once the code is actually executed, the array is created and memory allocated.

Comment: An array is an object in JS. Its storage (for the elements) is allocated on the heap where it can dynamically grow, while the variable (on the stack/in the registers) only holds the pointer to the heap.

Comment: Allocating dynamically-sized things doesn't really have anything to do with hoisting. (In fact hoisting, or the creation phase, is an artefact of stack frames being statically sized)